# What are my transportation options for visiting Doubtful Sound?

Tags: transportation, nature-and-wildlife, new-zealand

I would like to explore [Doubtful Sound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubtful_Sound) and looking on Google maps it doesn't look particularly accessible, so what are my options?

[image]
<sup>Photo credit: [Allie_Caulfield](http://www.flickr.com/photos/wm_archiv/) ([flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/28577026@N02/2795037985) / [Wikimedia Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Doubtful_Sound_Clear.jpg))</sup>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way is to go with a tour as the trip requires crossing Lake Manapouri and there's an hour long coach trip to Deep Cove. [For more information see the NZ Fiordland webpage](http://www.fiordland.org.nz/About-Fiordland/Maps/Manapouri--Doubtful-Sound.asp).

There are a couple of tour options, including overnight stays on a boat, a couple of companies:

- [Real Journeys](http://www.realjourneys.co.nz/Main/Doubtful/)
- [Doubtful Sound Cruise](http://www.doubtfulsoundcruise.com/)

As far as I remember the overnight stay options are quite popular so you'll need to book in advance.